# Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: zend-framework

Hi i have this zend framework project i already setup my web server and added the hosts on it when i tried to open the link on the browser this is what ive got and error message

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\soomedia_test\website\htdocs\index.php on line 20

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\soomedia_test\website\library;;;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\soomedia_test\website\htdocs\index.php on line 20
```

can someone help me figured this out the zend/application.php? where will i find this file?Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your system isn't finding Zend Framework library.
Try to put the library under **/yourproject/library**

Comment: Same issue that I had -- this works as Zend needs these files in the /project/library/ folder unless you change your /public/index.php file manually, @maco please mark the question as answered if it answered your question too.

Answer (score 0):

Your new project doesn't have the zend folder. Simply copy the `library/zend` folder of your downloaded zend framework to your new project `library/zend`.

This will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507